# VS Code Python Interactive Window Fails to Import `rasterio`

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, rasterio

I recently updated VS Code to 1.53.2 on Linux (elementaryOS using `snap` specifically). When trying to run an existing Python script in the Interactive Window, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio'`, so obviously it is not finding the `rasterio` module. I am using a Conda environment, and have confirmed that rasterio is actually installed in the environment, and I have the appropriate environment selected in VS Code.

The module is properly imported when using interactive Python from the terminal, calling the script from the terminal, running the command in a local Jupyter server, and even in Run and Debug Mode in VS Code. I therefore assume the issue is something to do with the Jupyter server used within VS Code. All the other modules I have looked at import just fine, so it seems to be some issue within VS Code specifically with the `rasterio` package. When using the interactive window, even just running the simple command

```py
import rasterio as rio
```

fails, again only in VS Code Python Interactive Window and nowhere else. Any thoughts or suggestions or what to do to resolve it, or should I just file an Issue in the VS Code Github repo?

In case it helps, here's the list of installed modules from a basic conda environment (only python3, jupyter, and rasterio installed) where `import rasterio` fails:

```yaml
name: scratch
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - affine=2.3.0=py_0
  - argon2-cffi=20.1.0=py39h3811e60_2
  - async_generator=1.10=py_0
  - attrs=20.3.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - backports=1.0=py_2
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.1=py_0
  - bleach=3.3.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - boost-cpp=1.74.0=hc6e9bd1_2
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h36c2ea0_0
  - ca-certificates=2020.12.5=ha878542_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=h7979940_1007
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py39hf3d152e_1
  - cffi=1.14.5=py39he32792d_0
  - cfitsio=3.470=hb418390_7
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
  - cligj=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - curl=7.71.1=he644dc0_8
  - dbus=1.13.6=hfdff14a_1
  - decorator=4.4.2=py_0
  - defusedxml=0.6.0=py_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1003
  - expat=2.2.10=h9c3ff4c_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=hba837de_1004
  - freetype=2.10.4=h0708190_1
  - freexl=1.0.5=h516909a_1002
  - geos=3.9.0=h9c3ff4c_0
  - geotiff=1.6.0=h2b14fbe_4
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=h0b5b191_1005
  - giflib=5.2.1=h36c2ea0_2
  - glib=2.66.7=h9c3ff4c_0
  - glib-tools=2.66.7=h9c3ff4c_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.3=h04508c2_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.3=h3560a44_0
  - hdf4=4.2.13=h10796ff_1004
  - hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_h6a2412b_1114
  - icu=68.1=h58526e2_0
  - importlib-metadata=3.4.0=py39hf3d152e_0
  - importlib_metadata=3.4.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - ipykernel=5.5.0=py39hef51801_1
  - ipython=7.20.0=py39hef51801_2
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - ipywidgets=7.6.3=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - jedi=0.18.0=py39hf3d152e_2
  - jinja2=2.11.3=pyh44b312d_0
  - jpeg=9d=h36c2ea0_0
  - json-c=0.15=h98cffda_0
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py_2
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py39hf3d152e_6
  - jupyter_client=6.1.11=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jupyter_console=6.2.0=py_0
  - jupyter_core=4.7.1=py39hf3d152e_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=1.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - kealib=1.4.14=he4dc956_1
  - krb5=1.17.2=h926e7f8_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=hea4e1c9_2
  - libblas=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libcblas=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libclang=11.0.1=default_ha53f305_1
  - libcurl=7.71.1=hcdd3856_8
  - libdap4=3.20.6=hd7c4107_1
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libev=4.33=h516909a_1
  - libevent=2.1.10=hcdb4288_3
  - libffi=3.3=h58526e2_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h2828fa1_18
  - libgdal=3.1.4=hbde00c8_6
  - libgfortran-ng=9.3.0=hff62375_18
  - libgfortran5=9.3.0=hff62375_18
  - libglib=2.66.7=h1f3bc88_0
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h2828fa1_18
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - libkml=1.3.0=h02e6976_1012
  - liblapack=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libllvm11=11.0.1=hf817b99_0
  - libnetcdf=4.7.4=nompi_h56d31a8_107
  - libnghttp2=1.43.0=h812cca2_0
  - libopenblas=0.3.12=pthreads_h4812303_1
  - libpng=1.6.37=h21135ba_2
  - libpq=13.1=hfd2b0eb_1
  - librttopo=1.1.0=hccdd1c9_5
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h36c2ea0_1
  - libspatialite=5.0.1=h04c9dda_2
  - libssh2=1.9.0=hab1572f_5
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=h6de172a_18
  - libtiff=4.2.0=hdc55705_0
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h7f98852_0
  - libxcb=1.13=h7f98852_1003
  - libxkbcommon=1.0.3=he3ba5ed_0
  - libxml2=2.9.10=h72842e0_3
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py39h3811e60_3
  - mistune=0.8.4=py39h3811e60_1003
  - mysql-common=8.0.23=ha770c72_1
  - mysql-libs=8.0.23=h935591d_1
  - nbclient=0.5.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert=6.0.7=py39hf3d152e_3
  - nbformat=5.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - ncurses=6.2=h58526e2_4
  - nest-asyncio=1.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - notebook=6.2.0=py39hf3d152e_0
  - nspr=4.29=h9c3ff4c_1
  - nss=3.62=hb5efdd6_0
  - numpy=1.20.1=py39hdbf815f_0
  - openjpeg=2.4.0=hf7af979_0
  - openssl=1.1.1j=h7f98852_0
  - packaging=20.9=pyh44b312d_0
  - pandoc=2.11.4=h7f98852_0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py_1
  - parso=0.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre=8.44=he1b5a44_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pip=21.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.40.0=h36c2ea0_0
  - poppler=0.89.0=h2de54a5_5
  - poppler-data=0.4.10=0
  - postgresql=13.1=h6303168_1
  - proj=7.2.0=h277dcde_2
  - prometheus_client=0.9.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.16=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.16=hd8ed1ab_0
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pycparser=2.20=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pygments=2.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pyqt=5.12.3=py39hf3d152e_7
  - pyqt-impl=5.12.3=py39h0fcd23e_7
  - pyqt5-sip=4.19.18=py39he80948d_7
  - pyqtchart=5.12=py39h0fcd23e_7
  - pyqtwebengine=5.12.1=py39h0fcd23e_7
  - pyrsistent=0.17.3=py39h3811e60_2
  - python=3.9.2=hffdb5ce_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python_abi=3.9=1_cp39
  - pyzmq=22.0.3=py39hea8fd45_0
  - qt=5.12.9=hda022c4_4
  - qtconsole=5.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtpy=1.9.0=py_0
  - rasterio=1.2.0=py39hb73aa6c_0
  - readline=8.0=he28a2e2_2
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py_0
  - setuptools=49.6.0=py39hf3d152e_3
  - six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - snuggs=1.4.7=py_0
  - sqlite=3.34.0=h74cdb3f_0
  - terminado=0.9.2=py39hf3d152e_0
  - testpath=0.4.4=py_0
  - tiledb=2.2.4=hb9a9e87_0
  - tk=8.6.10=h21135ba_1
  - tornado=6.1=py39h3811e60_1
  - traitlets=5.0.5=py_0
  - tzcode=2021a=h7f98852_0
  - tzdata=2021a=he74cb21_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1=py39hf3d152e_4
  - xerces-c=3.2.3=h9d8b166_2
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - xorg-libx11=1.6.12=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.10=h516909a_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h7f98852_1007
  - xz=5.2.5=h516909a_1
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h9c3ff4c_0
  - zipp=3.4.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h516909a_1010
  - zstd=1.4.8=ha95c52a_1
prefix: /home/durbank/miniconda3/envs/scratch
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue apparently lies with a bug in VS Code itself, as seen in [this Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116951), where the wrong environment is loaded when launching a Python Interactive Window.
I'll update this answer when the issue is resolved.